# get oids from agent (SNMP)

Tags: snmp

I have a SNMP agent running on Android.

I query it for a particular oid with a Python script (using pySNMP), and it's working right.

Is there any way to get all the oids available in the agent? with a Python script or another utility (I tested an utility called GetIf thinking that I could do that, but it doesn't allow me to configure the port)

I think is a stupid question, cause I wouldn't know what each oid is anyway, but I want to know if it is posible.

Comment: How about SNMP walk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a SNMP-walk beginning from the top node.
Search for pySNMP and bulk walk and you will find samples.